# control mbed led with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, mbed

I want to control the mBed controller with python 2.7 I tried this code as start

```
from mbedrpc import *

serdev = '/dev/tty.usbmodemfa122'

mbed = SerialRPC("/dev/tty.usbmodemfa122", 9600)

x = DigitalOut(mbed, "LED1")

x.write(1)
```

The code doesn't work means the led isn't activated. Do you know where is the error and have you any suggestion to solve it ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What board are you using and what version of mbed? It looks like you are trying to use RPC calls, which have been removed from the mbed mainline for several years now. So to use RPC with mbed you will need to use a board and program from ~3 years ago.

If you're interested you can use micropython on the microbit though!

Comment: I am using the mbed LPC1768. So it works for it ??
I don't have choice, I have to work with it and control it from python.

Comment: Sure, that should work then. You will just need to make sure that you are using a version of the mbed library that still has RPC in it (that was a wile ago, so finding an existing example program and importing it without updating it is your best bet).